# How can I trim the end of a zip code in vba?, only need the first 5 numbers. Need to go thru column and trim these numbers

Tags: excel, vba

'Need to trim zip code to first 5 digits, this is erroring out on me.

Dim l As Long
Dim m As Long

```
  m = Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
       j = 2
          For l = 2 To m
              Range("K2:K500").Value = Left(Range("K2:K500"), 5)
       j = j + 1
        
          Next l
```

Comment: `Range("K" & l).Value = Left(Range("K" & l).Value, 5)`.

Comment: Left cannot be applied to a range. Looking at your code you probably wanted to loop on each cell, not apply is on the whole K2:K500 range in one go. Try `Cells(l, 11).Value = Left(Cells(l, 11).Value, 5)`. You might also want to be explicit and specify the workbook and sheet and not using default.

Comment: got it to work thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in one go using `Evaluate`.

```
Sub TrimZips()

    With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K2:K500")
        .Value = Evaluate("LEFT(" & .Address(External:=True) & ",5)")
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm glad to see the generally increased use of the `External:=True` parameter in the `Range.Address` property at SO. Btw Would fully qualify the *outer* range reference, too - e.g. via `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(...)` or by the projects Code(Name) via `Sheet1.Range(...)` - in order to avoid referencing implicitly `ActiveSheet` where it isn't expected.